# Hadron as a flavor eigenstates

Tags: particle-physics

In section 8.2.1 of the book `Foundations of Perturbative QCD' by John Collins, there is a statement

> Normal targets (nucleons and pions) are flavor eigenstates,... An
>   exception would be DIS on a $K_L^0$ or $K_S^0$,...

What does he mean by a hadron being a flavor eigenstate or non-eigenstate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flavour eigenstates (also known as strong eigenstates) have definite quark flavour. For neutral kaons, these are $K^0$, which is a $\overline{s}u$ state, and $\overline{K}^0$, which is a $s\overline{u}$ state.
By contrast, the weak eigenstates $K^0_L$ and $K^0_S$ have definite lifetimes and are orthogonal linear combinations of $K^0$ and $\overline{K}^0$:

$$K^0_L = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\eta|^2}}\left(K^0 + \eta\overline{K}^0\right),$$

$$K^0_S = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\eta|^2}}\left(K^0 - \eta\overline{K}^0\right),$$

where $\eta$ is close to, but not exactly, 1. If $\eta=1$, then these would also be CP eigenstates.